# i want to rerender my component which used cache data by reactquery in react

Tags: reactjs, caching, render, react-query

hello i'm using react(next) with react-query

and i'm faced about render problem.

i am using cache data by react-query and i am changing my component by data's id.

but my browser cache my data by react-query.

so i'm fine when i request my data first-time.

but **when i comeback to my prev data my component is not rendered coz of cache data**

how can i fix this?? i want to render my component though i use **cache data**

```
react-query
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do Query Invalidation. check [here](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/query-invalidation) for context

Comment: yes i see but just only request query without rerender

Comment: the main use of query invalidation is to re-fetch data when you think data is stale. if you are using hooks this should automatically cause a re-render

Answer (score 0):

You should try setting cacheTime for those queries to 0. Reference [this](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/reference/useQuery)